# Is 'for x in array' always result in sorted x? [Python/NumPy]

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

For arrays and lists in Python and Numpy are the following lines equivalent:

```
itemlist = []
for j in range(len(myarray)):
    item = myarray[j]
    itemlist.append(item)
```

and:

```
itemlist = []
for item in myarray:
    itemlist.append(item)
```

I'm interested in the *order* of itemlist. In a few examples that I have tried they are identical, but is it *guaranteed*? For example, I know that the `foreach` statement in C# doesn't guarantee order, and that I should be careful with it.

Comment: Did you mean: for j in range(len(myarray)): ?

Comment: Oops, yes I did mean to throw in a range()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is guaranteed for lists.  I think the more relevant Python parallel to your C# example would be to iterate over the keys in a dictionary, which is NOT guaranteed to be in any order.

```
# Always prints 0-9 in order
a_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for x in a_list:
    print x

# May or may not print 0-9 in order. Implementation dependent.
a_dict = {'0':0,'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9}
for x in a_dict:
    print x
```

The `for <element> in <iterable>` structure only worries that the `iterable` supplies a `next()` function which returns something.  There is no general guarantee that these elements get returned in any order over the domain of the `for..in` statement; lists are a special case.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that arrays have a notion of order, that it is implemented via the next() function. The for ... in ... structure takes advantage of next(), and so data with an intrinsic order (arrays) implements next() differently than data without an intrinsic order (such as dictionaries.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's entirely guaranteed.  `for item in myarray` (where `myarray` is a *sequence*, which includes numpy's arrays, builtin lists, Python's array.arrays, etc etc), is in fact equivalent in Python to:

```
_aux = 0
while _aux < len(myarray):
  item = myarray[_aux]
  ...etc...
```

for some phantom variable `_aux`;-). Btw, both of your constructs are also equivalent to

```
itemlist = list(myarray)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I wasnt really trying to convert an array to a list, just exploring the order.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) guarantees this (emphasis is mine):

```
 for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
               ["else" ":" suite]
```

> "The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the
>   iterator, **in the order of ascending indices**."